# Select distinct values from each partition over()

Tags: postgresql, distinct, row-number

I have a query where I want questions from different categories based on their difficulty level.

There are questions which are similar to some other question (I am storing their linkages in a field called "bucket").

Now, what I want is that only 1 question should be returned from a bucket.

The query I am trying is:

```
select *
            from (
                select distinct q.bucket,
                    row_number() over (partition by dl.value order by random()) as rn,
                    dense_rank() over (partition by dl.value, LOWER(qc.value) = LOWER('general') order by random()) as rnc,
                    dl.value, qc.value as question_category,
                    q.question_text, q.option_a, q.option_b, q.option_c, q.option_d,
                    q.correct_answer, q.image_link, q.question_type
                from
                    questions_bank q
                    inner join
                    question_category qc on qc.id = q.question_category_id
                    inner join
                    sports_type st on st.id = q.sports_type_id
                    inner join
                    difficulty_level dl on dl.id = q.difficulty_level_id
                where st.game_type = lower('cricket') and dl.value in ('E','M','H')
            ) s
            where
                (value = 'E' and rnc <= 6 and LOWER(question_category) != LOWER('general')) or
                (value = 'E' and rnc <= 6 and LOWER(question_category) = LOWER('general')) or
                value = 'M' and rn <= 0 or
                value = 'H' and rn <= 0;
```

This is not returning the desired output.

Same output is:

```
bucket | rn | rnc | value | question_category | question_text | option_a | option_b | option_c | option_d | correct_answer |                 image_link                  | question_type 

  2 |  2 |   2 | E     | General           | abs           | a        | b        | c        | d        | option_a       | https://d1ugevkr3ygvej.cloudfront.net/2.png | i
  3 |  3 |   3 | E     | General           | abcd          | a        | b        | c        | d        | option_a       | https://d1ugevkr3ygvej.cloudfront.net/3.png | i
  3 |  4 |   4 | E     | General           | abs           | a        | b        | c        | d        | option_a       |                                             | t
  4 |  1 |   1 | E     | General           | image         | a        | b        | c        | d        | option_a       |                                             | t
```

If you notice, the bucket values contain 3 as duplicate value. I don't want a combination of row_number and bucket to be distinct. Priority should be given to bucket and then row numbers should be calculated but the partitions should be based on question_category values.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not to use `DISTINCT`, but

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (q.bucket) ...
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT).

This will return only one row per `q.bucket`, and if you add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query, it will pick the first row in that order (otherwise you'll get the “first best” row).

Comment: Thanks. It was such an easy solution.